# Summon fireball going same direction as arrow

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

**A bit of background before I ask the question:**

I am making a system of command blocks that finds in arrow in the ground and replaces it with a fireball. Right now I am making the fireball go directly into the ground, but that doesn't work very well when the arrow hits something on the side, as the fireball goes straight down.

**Question:**

How can I make it so the fireball spawns with a direction the same as the arrow in the ground?

**Current Command:**

```
/execute @e[type=Arrow,score_inGround_min=1] ~ ~ ~ summon Fireball ~ ~1 ~ {ExplosionPower:20, direction:[0.0,-10.0,0.0]}
```

Comment: Does it need to be a fireball, or can it just be an explosion?

Comment: It could just be an explosion, but I want to be able to control the size of it.

Comment: I believe creepers also allow you to control `ExplosionPower`... not 100% sure though. Edit: Not explosion power, but `ExplosionRadius`

Answer (score 3):

Do

```
/execute @e[type=Arrow] ~ ~ ~ summon Fireball ~ ~ ~ {direction:[0.0,0.0,0.0],ExplosionPower:1}
```

On a timer. It will remove the arrow though.

Answer (score -1):

You can hook this up to a always active repeating command block and then when you fire a snowball, it immediately transforms into a fireball and is thrusted into the direction that you threw it:

```
/execute @e[type=snowball] ~ ~ ~ summon Fireball ~ ~ ~ {direction:[0.0,0.0,0.0],ExplosionPower:0}
```

Comment: It works exactly like you would imagine. Its pretty darn awesome.

Comment: This is essentially no different than the already existing answer, apart from executing off a snowball instead of an arrow which is not what the question asked.